# JavaScript while loop simple JS

Tags: javascript

i've got a question. I've started this course on Udemy for JavaScript and we got to "while" loops. Now i get what while loops do, and i tried to create a simple number guessing game, but the thing back fired on me.

Here's the code:

```
var num = Number(prompt("What is the secret number?"));

while(num !== 354){
    var num = prompt("Guess the number!!!");
}
    alert("Correct number!!");
```

I've tried without Number () in var, i've tried with if and else, but it's not working. I mean it works, but when i type in any number it gives me "Guess the number!!!" info, but when i type in number "354" it gives me the same information. Now this is not a project, just exercise, but don't understand...

Thank you in advance guys

Comment: Your second `num` doesn't have the `Number` cast, so the `!==` doesn't work (string vs. number).

Comment: So i should add one more variable, like:

    var num = Number(prompt("What is the secret number?"));
    var realNum = num;

and then the rest of the code, but instead of "num" i should use "realNum"? I'll try that. Tnx

Comment: get rid for the 2nd "var " as well, it's poor form

Comment: @GoranSovilj `prompt` always returns a string. Testings `num !== '354'` would work.

Comment: And that is why i used Number(). I'm still on beginning, but shouldn't Number () reverse anything from string to a number (if the content of a string is a number)?

Comment: @GoranSovilj It does, but you only wrapped the passed the result of the first prompt into `Number( )`. The prompt in your loop doesn't have `Number( )`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a data Type issue. Specifically your input is still capturing a string and the while loop is expecting a valid type Number.

A simple method to ensure your data type is always what you need in this case would be `parseInt()`

Other methods:

Casting: using the [Number()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) function. Note: this has some limitation with Strings, particularly spaces.

[parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat): This will take an argument and spit out the Float value.

I added this to the `num` variable within `while()`

```js
var num = Number(prompt("What is the secret number?"));

while(parseInt(num) !== 354){
    var num = prompt("Guess the number!!!");
}
    alert("Correct number!!");
```

Comment: the use of `parseInt()` -> `while(parseInt(num) !== 354)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the strict comparison with type-converting one. This way your comparison captures both numeric and string data types.

Also, you don't really need to redeclare your variable in the loop body, you can safely omit `var` there then.

```js
var num = prompt("What is the secret number?");

while(num != 354){
    num = prompt("Guess the number!!!");
}

alert("Correct number!!");
```

Answer (score -1):

This code is working  (i used similar and edited it), but that one is not, where is the difference:

```js
    var answer = Number(prompt("What is the secret number?"));

    while(answer !== 354){
        var answer = prompt("Guess the number!!!");
    }

    alert("Yay, we made it!!!");
```

Comment: Please don't post another question as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Sorry man, still new to Stack. Don't know how to put the code, only as answer :(. But hey, the other code i placed, it's working, it's the same as the original, but the original is not working, this one is...

Comment: This one doesn't work, too. The strict comparison oprerator `!==` won't work. Replace it with type-converting comparison `!=` as suggested in my answer.

Comment: And `!=` did worked, however, this is also working:

`var answer = Number(prompt("What is the secret number?"));

while(answer !== 354){
    var answer = prompt("Guess the number!!!");
}

alert("Correct number!!!");
`  Seems that there is something when i select "num" as a variable. Don't know, but thanks, the information that you gave me was correct, but this is also somehow working, with `!==`

Comment: It doesn't work, I edited your answer to introduce the JSFiddle. Try to answer 1 and then 354 (so that you actucally execute the inner loop at least once). The variable name has nothing to do here.

Comment: Right, ty. I put answer 354 right away and that was ok, didn't preformed a loop. Ty man, sorry about this, i really want to learn and this is my first post on Stack :). You're awesome :).

Comment: No prob. The problem here is the comparison argument types and this is why Javascript has two comparison operators, the `===`/`!==` that is strict regarding types and `==`/`!=` that performs auto type conversions. Just use the latter here.

Comment: Nice, awesome, tnx :). I know the difference between `===` and `==`, but i forgot that for "not equal to", you change one `=` to `!` so it can be `!==` or `!=`. Tnx. But i thought that `Number()` on the first var would fix that. But i'll try to think this trough a bit more next time and fiddle with it more :).

Comment: If you put `Number()` on **both** that would fix it.